# Counting letters in a string returns incorrect number

Tags: c++, string, count

My teacher wants us to write a program that counts the number of letters (A-Z, a-z), numbers, and special characters in an input string. We are only allowed to use `<iostream>`.

My program counts the letters correctly, but I can't get a correct count of numbers or other characters. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>   //preprocessor directive
using namespace std;

//preprocessor directives


int main ()
{

//declare and initialize variables

    char s[50];
    int i;
    int letter = 0;
    int number = 0;
    int other = 0;


//user input

    cout << "Enter a continuous string of characters with no blank spaces" << endl;
    cout << "(example: aBc1234!@#$%)" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter your string: ";
    cin >> s;
    cout <<endl;

//loop through the string

//count letters

    i = 0;
    while (s[i] !=0)
    {
    if ((s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] < 'z') ||
        (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] < 'Z'))
        letter++;
    i++;
    }

//count numbers

    {
    if ((s[i] >= '0' && s[i] < '9'))
        number++;
    i++;
    }

//count other

    {
    if ((s[i] >= '!' && s[i] < ')'))
        other++;
    i++;
    }

//output results

    cout << "Your string has " << letter << " letters" << endl;
    cout << number << " numbers, and " << endl;
    cout << other << " other characters" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's an algorithm called `std::count_if` all ready for you to use and it's meant specifically for this. There are also character class testing functions like `std::isalpha`.

Comment: You need to put all of your conditionals within the while loop, and use an `if(...){...} else if(...){...} else{...}` construct.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast I'm certain that would not be an accepted solution in a class that hasn't even addressed buffer overflow from user input.

Comment: I do believe you want `<=` instead of `<` on your conditions for counting characters, right now it's not including 'z', 'Z', '9' or ')' in the counts

Comment: @user3754573 Your program's existing logic is not difficult to walk through, and clearly contains logic errors.  Consider at every point in the program what `i` contains, for example, and how that relates to  the length of the char array `s`.

Comment: @DavidO, Oh boy, I missed that. Please OP, don't do it! Save the buffers!

Comment: @DavidO: Everything works fine except the "other characters."     i = 0;
    while (s[i] !=0)
    {
    if ((s[i] >= '!' && s[i] <= ')'))
        other++;
    i++;
    }

Comment: This is what happens:   Enter your string: aBc1234!@#$%

Your string has 3 letters
4 numbers, and
​4 other characters

Comment: @jmoerdyk Thank you! I have one more question:                Everything works fine except the "other characters." i = 0; while (s[i] !=0) { if ((s[i] >= '!' && s[i] <= ')')) other++; i++; } –  user3754573 15 mins ago    
      
This is what happens: Enter your string: aBc1234!@#$% Your string has 3 letters 4 numbers, and ​4 other characters –

Answer (score 0):

Lets take this step by step.  I'm assuming you haven't been exposed to for loops yet, which are much cleaner for this type of iterative problem, so we will stick to while loops for now.  Your code up to the while loop is just fine, so I'll ignore it.  When you get to the while loop you are creating a variable i to keep track of your progress while looping through the character array, and then telling the while statement to loop until it encounters a 0, which stands for the null character (I'd actually change the 0 to '\0' which is exactly the same thing, but states your intentions more clearly).  So this means your loop will go character by character through the string and let you examine each one. So right now inside the while loop you have an if statement that checks if the current character at index i is a letter. If so, increment the letter count.  That is exactly what you want. But then you reach the end of the while loops execution block and return back to the conditional to check if the next character is the null character and then repeat the while block.  The if statements that handle checking if the character is a number or symbol are outside the while loop and therefore will not be executed for each character in the string. Instead they will be executed only once on s[i], which will be the null character since that is the index that i is  still pointing to after the while loop terminates. Your solution should be to move those two if statements into the while loop so that they will be run for each character in the string.

By the way, be careful of your character tests.  You aren't including all the characters.  For instance you are including all characters up to, but not including 'Z'.  Make sure to make those comparisons into <=.  Also more importantly, your check for 'other' characters will only catch some of the other characters on the keyboard.  I won't tell you exactly how to fix this, since it is a school assignment, but I will tell you it will involve using the else clause with your if statement (or even better the else if statement). If you don't know much about it yet, there are some excellent tutorials online.  For instance: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson2.html

Good luck, and have fun!